# How product leaks before announcements affect a company economically?

Tags: marketing, innovation

It happens specially for well known companies (e.g. Apple, Garmin, etc.) that some features of their products leaks into the media before the announcement. I was wondering what are the economical effects of these leaks on the company and how strong are they?

Answer (score 1):

**Opinion**

If the leak is close to a release date, I would say most of these are made on purpose, to feed expectations, leading to greater attention and publicity (and sales). I don't see how this can be negative for the company. In technological firms, most of the features are patent-protected so they cannot be copied anyway. However, if the leak were to happen long before a release, this could indicate rivals potential direction of own developments (either copying them or moving away/further than the competitors).

**Research**

Maybe the question is related to the literature on [knowledge leakage](http://www.emeraldinsight.com/doi/abs/10.1108/VINE-01-2015-0009?journalCode=vine), which relates to R&D, knowledge management, knowledge sharing, etc.

One [recent paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Snejina_Michailova/publication/265296435_Knowledge_sharing_knowledge_leaking_and_relative_innovation_performance_An_empirical_study/links/546e55fa0cf29806ec2eb1b0/Knowledge-sharing-knowledge-leaking-and-relative-innovation-performance-An-empirical-study.pdf)  mentions some of the costs:

> Knowledge leakage has various negative effects on
>   firms,
>   including loss of revenue, damaged reputation, loss of productivity
>   and costs arising from breached confidentiality agreements
>   (Ahmad et al., 2014). It also decreases bargaining power and even
>   creates new competitors for the original knowledge owner
>   (Baughn et al., 1997). Therefore, when an employee leaks knowl-
>   edge that is rare, inimitable and non-substitutable, recovery from
>   such leakage can be very challenging (Ahmad et al., 2014; Barney,
>   1991, 1996).

The same paper states that :

> Firms traditionally attempt
>   to protect their innovation-based competitive advantages with
>   intellectual property rights (IPRs), trademarks, copyrights or other
>   knowledge-protecting  mechanism

I suggest you look into those references if you want to get further insights.